# How to check which all schemas are having access to a view?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How can I check which all schemas are having access to a view like the table privileges present in DBA_TAB_PRIVS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access privileges for views are also in `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`.

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to find my view because the entry corresponding to that view was not present in sys.objauth$. Any idea why it could have happened?

Comment: No idea. On my database, views can be found in sys.objauth$.

Comment: I got it. There won't be any entry in sys.objauth$ if no one is having any privilege on that object.

Answer (score 0):

`DBA_TAB_PRIVS` is misnamed - it contains privileges not only for tables, but for all database objects (tables, views, packages, ...). So just use the same query as you use for your tables.

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to find my view because the entry corresponding to that view was not present in sys.objauth$. Any idea why it could have happened?